# Overflow hidden not working in my firefox

Tags: css

Overflow hidden not working in my firefox rest of the browser working fine

```css
select {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="" size="20">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

**Firefox Output**
[image]

**Other browser Output**
[image]

Comment: are you sure your css is in a valid css block?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: it seems to be a bug

Comment: You mean firefox bug or my code bug

Comment: @j08691 it's the version 60.0.1 for me ... and the scroll is appearing ... like there is no property

Comment: @Mytesting I meant FF bug

Comment: Ah I see so you're seeing the grey scroll area. But there's no scroll bar, correct?

Comment: @j08691 yes, he updated the question with image ;)

Comment: @j08691 Yes Correct

Comment: Version 60.0.1 i am using

Answer (score 0):

The overflow property is used when you want to control the element behavior if the content is bigger than the element size.

In your case, the container is bigger than the content so the content is not overflowing.

Perhaps what you want to do is adjust the size of the select to match the content, if that is the case you have to set the size of the select to match the number of options:

```css
select {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: After your description you kept the overflow? remove it and see  ... by the way did you test it? try the code within FF and remove/add the overflow to see the issue

Comment: check my image in FF & chrome

Comment: and check your code now on Chrom and FF ... We are having the scroll

Comment: Ok, I hadn't understood the question, if you remove the size attribute you can remove the scrollbar, but then you lose the ability to control the height...

Comment: Still appear in FF Scrool bar

Comment: IDK, I just tested on firefox on linux and I think it's working https://imgur.com/a/pH4prq5